# Entityframe work database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using this EF framework trying to learn it with the code first approach.  I've following a couple articles.  My question is where is my data base I've looked at this article [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706852/where-is-my-database-and-how-do-i-view-it) but still can not fid the db. I'm using VS 2012 and didnt specify the connection string so it should be in the local instance of the SQL express is my understanding with the fully qualified DB context name?

Here is my context class :

```
namespace EntityFrameWorkPluralSight
{
  class Context : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

  }
}
```

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have the SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Yes I cant find it in there either after refreshing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalDB was introduced in SQL Server 2012 CTP3. It’s basically a new version of SQL Express, with same functionality, dedicated to developers.

See here for more info :

[SQL Server (localdb)\v11.0 explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained)

Comment: thanks pointed me in the right direction took lot of reading to figure out what was going on  and additionally my connection using management studio was incorrect https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b75bef7e-13f3-4658-8d43-9df12ab4c320/connecting-localdb-using-sql-server-management-studio-express?forum=sqlexpress